# C code compiles silently with gcc, but raises a "truncated - malformed object" error in objdump

Tags: c, x86, x86-64

I have the following short and simple C file called `composition.c` :

```
long inside (long a1,long a2)
{
  return a1+a2-a1*a2;
}

long outside(long b1,long b2,long b3,long b4)
{
  long first_half = inside(b2,b3);
  long second_half = inside(b1,b4);
  return(first_half+second_half);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   long answer=outside(3,4,5,6);
   return 0;
}
```

In my terminal on my HighSierra MacBook Air, I did `gcc -g -O0 composition.c -o composition` and `objdump -d composition`, but the latter produces an error message :

```
$ objdump -d composition

composition:    file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/objdump: 'composition': truncated or malformed object (bad section index: 3 for symbol at index 2)
```

So I'm  asking what's wrong with my C code ?

Update : here are the version details :

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$ objdump --version
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
  Host CPU: broadwell

  Registered Targets:
    aarch64    - AArch64 (little endian)
    aarch64_be - AArch64 (big endian)
    arm        - ARM
    arm64      - ARM64 (little endian)
    armeb      - ARM (big endian)
    thumb      - Thumb
    thumbeb    - Thumb (big endian)
    x86        - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
    x86-64     - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
```

Comment: Probably nothing to do with the code but your toolchain.

Comment: Did you try a simpler program?

Comment: I just ran your code, just as it appears using gcc, (With compiler settings: _Have gcc follow the 2011 ISO C language standard_.   No problems were observed.  Also tried using just `-g`, also with no problems observed.  (I am running `gcc` from within `Code::Blocks` IDE, on Windows.)

Comment: Does objdump work with executables? What happens if you compile your C code into an object file (-c option with gcc) and run objdump on that?

Comment: I am not sure it matters, but when selecting debug symbols: `-g` at the same time selecting any of the optimization options within the CB IDE, gcc complains with a warning that _this is not a good idea_.

Comment: @ryyker (answer to your last comment) The problem stays the same if I remove the `-g` option to `gcc`

Comment: @ChrisTurner I need to view linked executable binaries, not just temporary object files

Comment: @ryyker: that's a Code::Blocks warning.  `gcc -O3 -g` from the command line doesn't give any warnings.  Depending what you want it for, "not a good idea" is an overstatement.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ the color highlighting of source lines <-> asm lines is done using debug info from `-g` and still works at high optimization levels.  Although some instructions don't have an associated source line, and some source lines don't have any instructions because of optimization.

Comment: Please include `gcc --version` & `objdump --version` output in your question.

Comment: @Kamil.S done, thx for the suggestion